# How do I set a “Max size” for a folder?

Tags: server, 20.04

I have a hard drive that is just for my cloud system, I need to be able to limit the folder size and prevent all the users from going over that size,

Comment: User24601 - It cannot be a new drive, it just has to be the directory,